# IOS Tableview in a scrollview heights

Tags: ios, scrollview, tableview

I have a `UITableView` nested within a `UIScrollView` and am finding it hard to calculate the height of either.

The content of both is dynamic so I'd like the tableview to expand to fit the content of it, and in turn the scrollview to expand to fit the content of the tableview.

I have this for the scrollview:

```
CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
for (UIView* view in contentView.subviews)
    {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
    }
```

But the resultant height is too long, too much scrolling.

The tableview I'm finding harder to get to dynamically resize, if I leave it without a defined size it is too small. So I added this:

```
self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, [self.tableView contentSize].height);
```

And that's too big.

I think the size of the tableview is dictated by the number and height of the rows within it but can't find a clear answer here or on the net.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use directly the scrollview of your table ?

Answer (score 0):

Your [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) should implement:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This will set the correct size for your cell.

Comment: THanks, this helps with setting the cell height alright but the tableview is still too long as is the scrollview. I must be setting something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to set the height of `UIScrollView`:

```
for (UIView* view in scrollview_.subviews)
{
    if (!view.hidden)
    {
        CGFloat y = view.frame.origin.y;
        CGFloat h = view.frame.size.height;
        if (y + h > scrollViewHeight)
        {
            scrollViewHeight = h + y;
        }
    }
}

[scrollview_ setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewHeight))];
```

To get the height of `UITableView`, maybe you can calculate like rowheight*rowcount